# Jupyter notebook Too slow and crashes browser

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[image]I am using the Jupyter notebook from latest Anaconda distribution for python 3.7x. When i tried to launch the Jupyter notebook, it takes too much time to load and the page becomes unresponsive in Chrome. At the same time, the other open tabs also freezes. I have also tried re-installation of the Anaconda but no luck. I have tried Firefox and its the same issue.

Comment: How about CPU and memory usage?

Comment: The CPU and memory usage is normal. it is pretty much normal while starting the notebook.